# Magento 2.3.2: setup:di:compile not working getting out in command line after 14%

Tags: magento2, command-line, setup-di-compile

Hey there i am trying to run command setup:di:compile . its getting started but and stopping for sometimes on 14% and then its gettin out back to cli.
[image]

i am not getting any error or exception so that i can solve it.

i have tried cache:flush , removed cache folder , removed generated folder but did not worked

how can i solve this issue help me to get the solution.

Big thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `app/bootstrap.php`

and check if below lines are commented then un-comment that lines and run compile command again.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks i got error

Comment: What is the error?